# How to throttle my cron worker form pushing messages to RabbitMQ?

Tags: node.js, cron, rabbitmq, message-queue

### Context:

We have micro service which consumes(subscribes)messages from 50+ RabbitMQ queues.

Producing message for this queue happens in two places

1. The application process when encounter short delayed execution business logic ( like send emails OR notify another service), the application directly sends the message to exchange ( which in turn it is sent to the queue ).
2. When we encounter long/delayed execution business logic We have `messages` table which has entries of messages which has to be executed after some time.

Now we have cron worker which runs every 10 mins which scans the `messages` table and pushes the messages to RabbitMQ.

### Scenario:

Let's say the messages table has 10,000 messages which will be queued in next cron run,

1. 9.00 AM  - Cron worker runs and it queues 10,000 messages to RabbitMQ queue.
2. We do have subscribers which are listening to the queue and start consuming the messages, but due to some issue in the system or 3rd party response time delay it takes each message to complete `1 Min`.
3. 9.10 AM - Now cron worker once again runs next 10 Mins and see there are yet 9000+ messages yet to get completed and time is also crossed so once again it pushes 9000+ duplicates messages to Queue.

**Note: The subscribers which consumes the messages are idempotent, so there is no issue in duplicate processing**

### Design Idea I had in my mind but not best logic

I can have 4 status ( RequiresQueuing, Queued, Completed, Failed )

1. Whenever a message is inserted i can set the status to `RequiresQueuing`
2. Next when cron worker picks and pushes the messages successfully to Queue i can set it to `Queued`
3. When subscribers completes it mark the queue status as `Completed / Failed`.

There is an issue with above logic, let's say RabbitMQ somehow goes down OR in some use we have purge the queue for maintenance.

Now the messages which are marked as `Queued` is in wrong state, because they have to be once again identified and status needs to be changed manually.

### Another Example

Let say I have RabbitMQ Queue named ( events )

This events queue has 5 subscribers, each subscribers gets 1 message from the queue and post this event using REST API to another micro service ( event-aggregator ). Each API Call usually takes 50ms.

Use Case:

1. Due to high load the numbers events produced becomes 3x.
2. Also the micro service ( event-aggregator ) which accepts the event also became slow in processing, the response time increased from 50ms to 1 Min.
3. Cron workers follows your design mentioned above and queues the message for each min. Now the queue is becoming too large, but i cannot also increase the number of subscribers because the dependent micro service (  event-aggregator ) is also lagging.

Now the question is, If keep sending the messages to events queue, it is just bloating the queue.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html - While reading this page, i found out that rabbitmq won't even accept the connection if it reaches high watermark fraction (default is 40%).  Of course this can be changed, but this requires manual intervention.

So if the queue length increases it affects the rabbitmq memory, that is reason i thought of throttling at producer level.

### Questions

1. How can i throttle my cron worker to skip that particular run or somehow inspect the queue and identify it already being heavily loaded so don't push the messages ?
2. How can i handle the use cases i said above ? Is there design which solves my problem ? Is anyone faced the same issue ?

Thanks in advance.

### Answer

Check the accepted answer Comments for the throttling using queueCount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine QoS - (Quality of service) and Manual ACK to get around this problem.
Your exact scenario is documented in https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html. This example is for python, you can refer other examples as well.

Let says you have 1 publisher and 5 worker scripts. Lets say these read from the same queue. Each worker script takes 1 min to process a message. You can set QoS at channel level. If you set it to 1, then in this case each worker script will be allocated only 1 message. So we are processing 5 messages at a time. No new messages will be delivered until one of the 5 worker scripts does a MANUAL ACK.

If you want to increase the throughput of message processing, you can increase the worker nodes count.

The idea of updating the tables based on message status is not a good option, DB polling is the main reason that system uses queues and it would cause a scaling issue. At one point you have to update the tables and you would bottleneck because of locking and isolations levels.

Comment: Hi @gowtham Thanks for your inputs, my question was around how can i throttle my cron from queueing the messages repeated if the drain rate is slow. I have added another use case for clarification.

Comment: Hi @sathish, thanks for clarification. When you declare a queue on the client side - you get a return 3 values - name,messages, consumers. Messages is number of messages that not waiting for acknowledgement. You can check the value of this count before you publish your message. Another way is to set a policy for queue length - say 10000 and listen for pub confirms. Another way is to use rabbitmq prometheus metrics - per object metrics and look for ready messages value. Hope these help !!

Comment: Wow @Gowtham i had no idea about this, do you have any article or blog describing this ? Can you point me in that direction ?

Comment: Queue size - check any driver - python/nodejs/golang documentation for setting this while declaring the queue and then check the driver doc again for the return values. If you need more info you can check how setting a queue size works at https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html  For prometheus metrics you can refer https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html.  I am sure setting a queue size and then inspecting the return value will help you resolve your requirement.

Comment: Yeah. Setting queue size and return values is the one solves the problem, let me check driver API.. But for queue which is declared already, we will be acquiring a channel and use that channel publish message. That is were i was wondering how channel might know queue size.

Comment: Found it @gowtham thanks for your answer. Do upvote the question for everyone reachability who are facing same kind of issue. Also add these comments as answers :)